# Applying a style to text that I double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edited to reword:

I have an input box

```
<input type="text" id="some_id" />
```

I enter some text in it in the browser:

```
Here is my text!
```

Now suppose I double click on the word "my", can I:

Capture this value? Yes, that answer is below.

Can I style this in place in the text input to make it bold or highlight?

In the text input after I double click it would end up looking like:

Here is **my** text!

Comment: Yes, it is is possible. Can you show us what you have done to accomplish this?

Comment: interesting question...but you need to show us what you  have done?

Comment: So far I am at the point of - I have an input box with text in it.

Comment: wow..incredible..delete this question..try what you have asked and then if you are stuck...post your questions..

Comment: MESSIAH - u just here for the sweet sweet karma?

Comment: @NickTomlin I don't think is possible, at least not with an `<input type='text' />`. You can fake it with a div or something else. How would you implement it with an `<input text>` element? I am interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want only the word selected (via the double click default behaviour)

```
$('input').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).addClass(yourClass);
    alert(getSelected());
});
```

using the getSelected function found from http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

```
getSelected = function(){
    var t = '';
    if(window.getSelection){
        t = window.getSelection();
    }else if(document.getSelection){
        t = document.getSelection();
    }else if(document.selection){
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}
```

applying a class to ONLY the selected text.. that i don't know if its possible

Comment: "applying a class to ONLY the selected text.. that i don't know if its possible" - is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible.

this is a example of getting the text from input

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="inputbox"/>
```

JS :

```
$("input#inputbox").dblclick( function(e) {
   alert($(this).val());

 });
```

And another approach to do it in a document text not in the inputbox

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function(){
         var s = window.getSelection();
        s.modify('extend','backward','word');        
        var b = s.toString();

        s.modify('extend','forward','word');
        var a = s.toString();
        s.modify('move','forward','character');
         alert(b+a);

    });
});
```

yoiu can try the above example in here http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/rD2uE/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [`dblclick`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/): http://jsfiddle.net/d9DfM/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Le javascript:

```
$('#input').dblclick(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', "red");
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Nope. He wants to highlight only the text selected. This is not possible to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sometextval").dblclick(function(){
        myval = $("#sometextval").val(); 
        alert(myval);
    });

})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9mcL/

Comment: have you posted the answer at wrong place???what has the OP asked and what you are answer is...